# How to rewrite on a file

Tags: python

So, I'm writing a program where a user takes a card from a certain pile. I have the number of cards in each pile written out in a text file. The file looks like this:

```
A, 10

B, 9

C, 7

D, 8
```

There are 4 piles, A, B, C, D. The comma separates the pile name from the number of cards in that pile. When the user inputs the pile that they're taking a card from and then how many cards they are taking from the pile, I would like for the program to then rewrite the number of cards in the pile to the number of cards in that pile once the user has taken cards out. So, for example, the user takes 3 cards from pile B, so I would like for the program to automatically change the 9 cards in pile B to 9-3 = 6 cards in that pile.

This is the code that I've written:

```
pile = input("Which pile are you taking a card from?") 

number = input("How many cards are you taking from this pile?")
f = open("cardfile.txt", "r+")

found = 0
for line in f.readlines():
    b = line.split(", ")
    if (b[0])==pile):
        found = 1
        oldnumber = int(b[1])
        newnumber = oldnumber - int(number)
```

I would like to replace `b[1]` in the text file with the value of the variable `newnumber`. How do I do this?

Comment: store all the data in a data structure. And then change the values as you need and after that override the file

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: See my answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

```
pile = input("Which pile are you taking")
number = input("How many cards")
dict = {};
with open("cardfile.txt","r+") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        name,num = line.split(", ")
        dict[name] = int(num)
        if(name==pile):
            found =1
            oldnumber = int(num)
            newnumber = oldnumber - int(number)
            dict[name] =newnumber

out = open("cardfile.txt","w")
for d in dict:
    out.write(d+", "+str(dict[d])+"\n")
out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first get all the lines in the file and close the file. Then, iterate over the lines to find the line number corresponding to the relevant card and the new number to write to that line. Finally, modify the element of the list corresponding to the relevant line and write all lines back to the file:

```
pile = input("Which pile are you taking a card from?")
number = input("How many cards are you taking from this pile?")

# Prefer to use the with statement which closes the file for you
with open('cardfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    card_counts = f.readlines()

for i, card_count in enumerate(card_counts):
    b = card_count.split(", ")
    if b[0] == pile:
        new_number = int(b[1]) - int(number)
        line_position = i
        break

card_counts[i] = str(b[0]) + ',' + str(new_number)

with open('cardfile.txt', 'wb') as wf:
    wf.writelines(card_counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a textfile with python, you can only append, write, or read text. So in this case I would store the new values in a list and then rewrite them to the textfile after.

```
pile = input("Which pile are you taking a card from?") 

number = input("How many cards are you taking from this pile?")
f = open("cardfile.txt", "r")

lines2write = []
for line in f.readlines():
    b = line.split(",")
    if b[0] == pile:
        line = "{},{}\n".format(b[0], int(b[1])-int(number))
    lines2write.append(line)
f.close()

# rewrite to the textfile
ftw = open("cardfile.txt", "w")
for line in lines2write:
    ftw.write(line)
ftw.close()
```